# Why did this timestamp get written into 2 nodes instead of 1?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the function below to get the server timestamp for Firestore:

```
FieldValue getFirestoreTimestamp() {
  return FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

I am using this value in both Firestore and Realtime Database. In Firestore, this seems to get written fine: `Jul 25, 2023 08:33 PM`. The problem is in Realtime Database. I'm using a Firestore trigger to populate RTDB with some information when a record is created in Firestore. The node I populate in RTDB needs a timestamp. I want to reuse the same timestamp that was determined on the client (function above) in both Firestore and RTDB for uniformity. The problem is that when I write this same timestamp to RTDB, it doesn't write it as a single node. It should write it as `createdAdminTimestamp: 1690337178000`, but instead it wrote it like this:

[image]

The trigger that wrote this timestamp:

```
function firestoreTrigger() {
  ...
  const createDate = documentData.createDate;

  await setGroupAdminRTDB(groupID, adminUID, adminUsername, createDate);

  ...
}


async function setGroupAdminRTDB(
  groupID: string,
  adminUID: string,
  adminUsername: string,
  createdAdminTimestamp: number
): Promise<{ returnVal: number; returnMsg: string }> {
  let returnVal = 0;
  let returnMsg = "";

  const nodeRef = await admin
    .database()
    .ref("app/groups/" + groupID + "/admin/")
    .once("value");

  const data = nodeRef.val();

  if (data == null) {
    try {
      const adminData = {
        adminUsername: adminUsername,
        createdAdminTimestamp: createdAdminTimestamp,
      };

      await admin
        .database()
        .ref("app/groups/" + groupID + "/admin/" + adminUID)
        .set(adminData);

      returnVal = 1;
      returnMsg = "Data successfully added!";
    } catch (error) {
      returnVal = 0;
      returnMsg = "ERROR: " + error;
    }
  } else {
    returnVal = 0;
    returnMsg = "Error: data already exists at admin node";
  }

  return { returnVal: returnVal, returnMsg: returnMsg };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Firestore and Realtime Database use a different format to store times, and you will need to convert between them.

In fact, Realtime Database doesn't have any native format to store date/time - since JSON doesn't define a type for that. The common convention is to store timestamps in Realtime Database as milliseconds since the epoch.

So you will need to convert the value from the `Timestamp` object in Firestore to milliseconds since the epoch that you then store in Realtime Database.

It's unclear to me how you get the timestamp from Firestore, but if it's a [`Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp) you can call `toMillis()` on it to get the value you can store in  Realtime Database.